# Fixed points of one-point-compactification

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, compactifications

Let $M$ be a locally compact (Hausdorff) space, and $g:M\to M$ an isomorphism (think of an action of a finite cyclic group).
By some generalities one can show that the "obvious" map $(M^g)^+\to(M^+)^g$ is continuous. Here $M^+$ is the one-point-compactification, and $M^g$ are the fixed points with the subspace topology. (One extends $g$ to a pointed map on $M^+$, that is $g(+)=+$).

Edit: if $M$ happens to be compact, $M^+=M\coprod +$ is the disjoint union with a point.

Is it true that this is an isomorphism? A (weak and/or equivariant) homotopy equivalence?
Is an appropriatly modified statement true in a "convenient" category of topological spaces?

Comment: I guess that if $M^g$ is already compact then you still add a point to it in $(M^g)^+$?

Comment: Exactly! Also only then is the "obvious" map a bijection.

Comment: I think it's pretty straightforward. What have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Oh you are right, i feel a bit foolish now. It is a continuous bijection between compact Hausdorff spaces, thus an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$M^+$ is still Hausdorff, so also $(M^+)^g$ is. Now we observe that the "obvious" map is a continuous bijection from a compact to a Hausdorff space, thus by standard textbook contents, an isomorphism.